# Modeling in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, modeling

now I'm working on a university project that I must define a building plan in NetLogo. 
I imported the geometry of our plan, for example, the start and end point of the walls and the geometry of doors. I wanna know that how can I draw walls and doors in NetLogo with patches and determining walls for agents that cannot exit and doors that can exit. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There are two elements here - display the walls, and have them work as barriers. For displaying, look up `pcolor` in the NetLogo dictionary. For barriers, search for 'walls' in the Model Library. Then come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @ JenB, Thank you for your help, I saw walls in Modal Library. I wanna know how to define this patches as barriers between two points that I import the coordinate of them(x, y, z).

Comment: Then you need to write a specific question that shows example data for the coordinates, the code you have written already that tries to set up coordinates as barriers and describes the problem you are having (eg specific error message, or that the turtle moves through the wall or ...). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are looking for examples you could check out the Pac-Man example in the models library. They are working with a lot of walls there.